# Does webgl drawArray() empty/discard the buffers?

Tags: performance, webgl, render

Trying to speed up the display of many near-identical objects in WebGL, I tried (naively, I guess), to re-use the buffers content. In the drawing routine of each object, I have (somewhat simplified):

```
if (! dataBuffered) {
  dataBuffered = true;
  :
  : gl stuff here: texture loading, buffer binding and filling
  :
}
// set projection and model-view matrices
gl.uniformMatrix4fv (shaderProgram.uPMatrix, false, pMatrix);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv (shaderProgram.uMVMatrix, false, mvMatrix);
// draw rectangle filled with texture
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, starVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
```

My idea was that the texture, vertex, and texture coordinates buffer are the same, but the model-view matrix changes (same object in different places). But, alas, nothing shows up. When I comment the `dataBuffered = true`, it's visible.

So my question is, does `drawArray()` discard or empty the buffers? What else is happening? (I'm working along the lessons at [learningwebgl.com](http://learningwebgl.com), if that matters.)

Comment: You'll need to post more code or a working example somewhere (jsfiddle?). No, drawArrays does not discard nor empty any buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is, Yes, you can reuse all the state you've set up for more than one gl.drawArrays().

http://omino.com/experiments/webgl/simplestWebGlReuseBuffers.html is a little example where it just changes one uniform float (Y-scale) and redraws, twice for every tick.

(In this case there's no textures, but some other state stays sticky.)

Hope that helps!

```
uniformSetFloat(gl,prog,"scaleY",1.0);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, posPoints.length / 3);

uniformSetFloat(gl,prog,"scaleY",0.2);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, posPoints.length / 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for assurance - there's been another error in there which was preventing anything to show up.